# How to make a text box always display a variables value

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, textbox

How would i make txbroot always show the value of root, because at the moment I will still show my current directory (this is in VB.net 2010)

```
Private Sub btnrootbrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnrootbwse.Click
        ' Creates a FolderBrowserDialog object
        Dim fbdroot As New FolderBrowserDialog
        'Dialog
        With fbdroot
            ' Desktop is the root folder in the dialog.
            .RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
            ' Select the C:\Windows directory on entry.
            .SelectedPath = CurDir()
            ' Prompt the user with a custom message.
            .Description = "Please Select Root Of Sever"
            root = .SelectedPath
            If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                txbroot.Text = root
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can't understand what do you want exactly

Comment: Basically, The problem is that as the code runs through and txbroot.text is set before root is change by the dialog. This means that the text displayed in txbroot is the current directory instead of the directory selected by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root affectation should be performed after ShowDialog

```
If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    root = .SelectedPath
    txbroot.Text = root
End If
```